# curve fitting complicated equation with numpy linalg lstsq

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a complicated function of three parameters a,b,c and one argument, nu:
[image]

Python code equivalent to this is:

```
a / (1 + (nu/b)**2)**(c/2)
```

I am used to using numpy linalg lsqst or the scipy equivalent to curve fit e.g. x, x^2, x^4, or orthogonal coefficients.

In this case how do I build up the shape `(3,len(nu))` first argument to lsqst?

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket `)` in your denominator

Comment: That's a typo in the TeX --  the quantity (1 + (...)) is raised to the c/2 power.

Comment: Do you have to use numpy's lstsq? It would be much more easier to use [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) instead.

Comment: the equation can be written in the form `1/a + (x/b)^2 / a = f^(-2/c) ` so `a` and `b` can be deduced from a linear fit on the form: `A + B*x^2 = F(c)` but a non-linear optimization remains to find c...

Comment: @JohnnyDrama I can use curve_fit or any other standard scientific python stack method to get at the a,b,c parameters.  What is important is only knowing their values (and perhaps R^2 on the fit, but that is a secondary concern).  I tried using curve_fit with real data and I get an overflow error which probably just happens from the algorithm trying a value that is very large for c, and the parameters it estimated were nonsensical.  I also tried fitting the formula against itself and got good values back, but also encountered overflow along the way.  Perhaps this function is ill-conditioned.

Comment: I can give a .npy file or .pkl or something with a real dataset that I would like to know the values of a,b,c of if that would be helpful.

Comment: Because you have a dataset with known a,b,c values, would you please test that dataset on my posted nonlinear fitting code and report the results?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I don't have a (real) dataset with a,b,c values.  I can synthesize a dataset by evaluating the formula, and feeding it to something like `curve_fit` or `lsqst` and seeing if it estimates a,b,c correctly.  The data in your formula does not appear to be the same equation as the python code I posted.  The TeX contains a typo.

Comment: I read your comment where you stated " I tried using curve_fit with real data and I get an overflow error" and misunderstood that to mean you have real data *with a,b,c*. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot format code in a comment I have placed it here. This is an all-nonlinear fitting and graphing example using your equation and scipy's curve_fit() on my test data. The scipy.optimize.differential_evolution genetic algorithm module used to estimate initial parameters for the nonlinear solver. This scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space and that algorithm requires parameter bounds within which to search - this example uses the max and min data values for those bounds. In your case, you may need to search different parameter bounds if you know what range of parameter values to expect.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


def func(nu, a, b, c):
    return  a / (1.0 + (nu/b)**2.0)**(c/2.0)


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    maxXY = max(maxX, maxY)
    minXY = max(minX, minY)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minXY, maxXY]) # seach bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minXY, maxXY]) # seach bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([minXY, maxXY]) # seach bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# generate initial parameter values
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)

print('Parameters', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```